# Баг с transition CSS

Tags: html, css, transition

При наведении мыши фотография m_pic плавно меняется на hid, но ПОСЛЕ того как убираешь мышь с объекта, смена фотографий происходит очень резко. С перва резко появляется фотография m_pic а вот hid появляется плавно. Пожалуйста подскажите в чем проблема? или может быть моя реализация плавной смены фотографий при наведении мыши не годится?

```css
 .pl_img{
        position:relative;
    }

    .hid{
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
    .m_pic{
        position:relative;
        opacity:1;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
    .player:hover .hid{
        position:relative;
        opacity:1;
    }
    .player:hover .m_pic{
        position:absolute;
        opacity:0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="player">
        <div class="pl_img">
            <img src="http://hc-avto.ru//media/players/mhl_list_image_galkin_vladimir_cc573d253801503ee6abf27797717124.jpg" class="m_pic">
            <img src="http://hc-avto.ru/media/players/mhl_hover_image_galkin_vladimir_cc573d253801503ee6abf27797717124.jpg" class="hid">
        </div>
        <div class="pl_content">
            <h3>Имя Фамилия</h3>
            <table><tbody><tr><th>Дата рождения</th><th>Рост</th><th>Вес</th></tr><tr><td>15.06.2000</td><td>185</td><td>75</td></tr></tbody></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я убрал `position: relative;`

```css
    .hid{
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
    }
    .m_pic{
        position: absolute;
        opacity:1;
        transition:  0.3s ease;
    }
    .player:hover .hid{
        opacity:1;
    }
    .player:hover .m_pic{
  
        opacity:0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="player">
        <div class="pl_img">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK1my.png?s=48&g=1" class="m_pic">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdUBG.jpg?s=32&g=1" class="hid">
        </div>
        <div class="pl_content">
            <h3>Имя Фамилия</h3>
            <table><tbody><tr><th>Дата рождения</th><th>Рост</th><th>Вес</th></tr><tr><td>15.06.2000</td><td>185</td><td>75</td></tr></tbody></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Все получилось :)

Comment: @GiorgiKsovreli рад помочь